# How do you update an observableArray item in knockout.js when input field is updated

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I am very new to using knockout and feel like some of the things I am doing are kind of hacky, so let me know if what I am doing here is wrong and I should be doing it a better way.

One of the properties of my model is an array of strings. In the UI, I am creating an input field for each item in the array.

What I want is for the items in the model to be updated as I update the values of the input fields.

Assuming I have a property called CarRentalCodes, which is an observableArray, here is part of my view

```
     <div data-bind="foreach: CarRentalCodes()">
         <input type="text" style="width:40px; display:inline" class="form-control" data-bind="value: $data"/>
     </div>
```

It lists out the input fields with the correct values, but as I change them they are not updated in the model.

Do I need to replace the values manually with javascript or is there something built in to knockout that can solve this problem for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the docs they are very good.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#key-point-an-observablearray-tracks-which-objects-are-in-the-array-not-the-state-of-those-objects

What you need to do is hook up the input to an observable instead of just a string.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/edhedges/ssekY/ and since it must be accompanied by code:

```
function vm() {
    this.myArr = ko.observableArray([
        new myObj('1'),
        new myObj(''),
        new myObj('hello'),
        new myObj('there')
    ]);
}

function myObj(myObjs) {
    this.myObs = ko.observable(myObjs);
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Comment: That worked for me. Instead of just pushing strings in to an ovservableArray, I am pushing {val: ko.observable(value)}. Now I can see changes as they are made. Thanks!

Comment: @bsayegh yeah that was just me being lazy as to how i was putting data into the array. Glad it worked for ya.